# indices of NumPy arrays intersection

Tags: python, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays. For example:

```
arr1 = np.array(['a','b','a','c','c','b','a','d'])
arr2 = np.array(['a','b','c','d'])
```

My task is to create list of indices of `arr2` array where `arr1 == arr2`.

The length of the desired list should be equal to `len(arr1)`. For instance, in my case the correct answer is `[0,1,0,2,2,1,0,3]`.

What is the short way to do this? Is it possible to use a list comprehension here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if `numpy` has a method for this, but here is a builtin approach, which takes O(N) in time:

```
In [9]: lookup = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(arr2)}

In [10]: [lookup[v] for v in arr1]
Out[10]: [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that arr2 is sorted, is that by design? If so you can do:

```
arr1 = np.array(['a','b','a','c','c','b','a','d'])
arr2 = np.array(['a','b','c','d'])

arr2.searchsorted(arr1)
# array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3])
```

As @JAB has mentioned you could use the sorter keyword to searchsorted when arr2 is not sorted:

```
arr2 = np.array(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
sorter = arr2.argsort()
sorter[arr2.searchsorted(arr1, sorter=sorter)]
# array([3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0])
```

This is an O(N*log(N)) method because of the argsort, but it should still be very fast for many use-cases.

Comment: Even if `arr2` weren't sorted, you could do `arr2.searchsorted(arr1, sorter=arr2.argsort())` to achieve the same effect without actually sorting `arr2`. Either way, this is probably more memory-efficient than Mr E's answer, though I haven't done a time comparison to see which takes longer.

Comment: Yes I think this is the best answer if arr2 is sorted

Comment: @JAB, Good point but keep in mind that if you're going to use the sorter, you need to use `sorter[a.searchsorted(key, sorter=sorter)]` to get the index in the original array.

Comment: @BiRico my arr2 is not sorted actually

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this with NumPy using broadcasting, however if your arrays are large you can end up allocating a lot of memory for the intermediate result

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1, arr2 = np.array(['a','b','a','c','c','b','a','d']), np.array(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> arr1 == arr2[:, None]
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> (arr1 == arr2[:, None]).argmax(axis=0)
array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3])
>>>
```

Otherwise keep an eye on [`arraysetops`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py) in case someone adds a `return_index` parameter to `intersect1d`

Comment: Not only that; should be much faster than the other one, for bigger datasets.

Comment: Using `arr2[:, np.newaxis]` might be slightly more clear about what that indexing operation does.